# Upvote or downvote to the users posts

Tags: database, laravel, oauth-2.0, phpmyadmin, postman

> i want to upvote or downvote to post posted by other user.user will
>   upload a post,i

migration for vote table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('votes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->unsignedInteger('post_id');
        $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');
        $table->integer('vote');
        $table->boolean('hide')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Route file

> api.php

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>[
                'auth:api', \App\Http\Middleware\OnlyRegisteredUsers::class]
            ], function(){
    /**
     * Group for registered users only APIs
     */
    Route::post('saveMedia','UserController@saveMedia');
    Route::post('voteToPost','UserController@voteToPost');
});
```

> Controller

```
public function voteToPost(Request $request)
{
    $userid = $request->user()->id;
    $postid = $request->get('post_id');
    $vote = $request->get('vote');
    $votecount = DB::table('votes')->where('user_id', $userid)->where('post_id', $postid)->wherea('hide', 0)->count();
    if($votecount == 0){
        DB::table('votes')
            ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'votes.user_id')
            ->leftJoin('posts', 'posts.id', '=', 'votes.post_id')
            ->where(['votes.hide' => 0, 'votes.user_id' =>$userid, 'votes.post_id' =>$postid])
            ->updateOrInsert([
                'user_id' => $userid,
                'post_id' => $postid,
                'vote' => $vote,
                'hide' => 0,
                'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
                'updated_at' => Carbon::now()
            ]);
    }
}
```

> i am getting the following error
>       "message": "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'hide' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select exists(select * from `votes` left join `users` on `users`.`id` = `votes`.`user_id` left join `posts` on `posts`.`id` = `votes`.`post_id` where (`votes`.`hide` = 0 and `votes`.`user_id` = 3 and `votes`.`post_id` = 6) and (`user_id` = 3 and `post_id` = 6 and `vote` = 1 and `hide` = 0 and `created_at` = 2018-10-05 11:44:38 and `updated_at` = 2018-10-05 11:44:38)) as `exists`)",

Comment: What is your question? you got some error?

Comment: Quesion is unclear. You have to specify what is your problem. what are you trying to do, what problems you faced? or others will down-vote your question

Comment: why there is such a complicated code? you just simply need to increment `vote` column for a particular `post`, don't you?

Comment: @TharakaDilshan  what  if i want to downvote any post or remove the upvote

Comment: @TharakaDilshan i'm looking for this only.just check the answer.

Comment: @sanduniYW i've forgot to post complete code

Answer (score 0):

```
public function voteToPost(Request $request){
        $userid = $request->user()->id;
        $postid = $request->get('post_id');
        $vote = $request->get('vote');
        $user = User::where(['id'=>$userid, 'hide'=>0])->first();
        $post = DB::table('posts')->where(['id'=>$postid, 'hide'=>0])->first();
        if($user && $post && in_array($vote, [0,1,-1])){
                DB::table('votes')
                    ->updateOrInsert(['user_id'=>$userid, 'post_id'=>$postid],[
                        'user_id' => $userid,
                        'post_id' => $postid,
                        'vote' => $vote,
                        'hide' => 0,
                        'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
                        'updated_at' => Carbon::now()
                    ]);
                return ['message'=>'ok'];
        }
        return abort(403, 'Invalid request');
    }
```

Comment: I see a one problem here, if a vote already exists, this overrides the vote amount, instead of increment or decrement it.. good luck

Comment: @TharakaDilshan exactly increment or decrement does't matter is this case,what i want is exsting vote should override and sorry bro by mistake i've flagged your comment as am not aware about the meaning of flag, i thought it's for useful purpose ,how to  revert  it back.